# crashlytics point this error RangeError (length): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0. Error thrown null

Tags: flutter

I have an error at this line

```
if (dateList1[0]==""||dateList1[0]==null){
```

error

```
Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: RangeError (length): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0. Error thrown null.
```

I don't know why I have a null error, I check if dateList1[0]==null

### Here is my code

```
      var dateList1;

      int indexToRemove = 0;

      List newList = dateList0.where((x) => dateList0.indexOf(x) != 
      indexToRemove).toList();
      
      dateList1=newList;

      if (dateList1[0]==""||dateList1[0]==null){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a chance that dateList1 is empty so the index 0 doesn't exist. You can do a check to find if its empty too like

```
if (dateList1.length > 0 && (dateList1[0]==""||dateList1[0]==null)){
```

Comment: When I try to reproduce the error I get
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 and not RangeError (length)